Selenium wont change selected Value
Following HTML Code:
<select id="standort.ort" name="standort.ort" class="input big">
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
</select>

I want to change the Value with Selenium, code as follows:
select_element = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, "standort.ort")
selector = Select(select_element)
# Different Variations underneath

Variations:
# Try 1
selector.select_by_visible_text("Value 2") # --> changes back instantly

# Try 2
for option in selector.options:
    if option.text == "Value 2":
        option.click() # ---> changes back instantly

# Try 3
for option in selector.options:
    if option.text == "Value 2":
        self.browser.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("standort.ort").options[{option.get_attribute("index")}].selected = true')
# Changes the value until the next action/click is performed

I also tried action chains but the value always gets resetted.
Here is a gif of what is happening: 
There are no infos in the dev console in the browser or any network calls. I tried with Chrome and Firefox Webdrivers.

try link the website you're tring to automate

You cant access it without an account (which you cant create)

Your code works fine, the first attempts works great
